# how to get a list from table based on a single date using hibernate query language

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hql

*I have a table named ordertab from (Order entity) with 5 columns and i have to get a list of rows based on the date i pass in showAllOrders(LocalDate date).

Here is the entity class. I am using junit5 to test this. I am new to both hibernate,junit and postgres.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ordertab")
public class Order {
    @Id
    private int orderId;

    private LocalDate orderDate;
    private LocalDate dispatchDate;
    private float totalCost;
    private String status;
    public Order() {
    };
    public Order(int orderId,LocalDate orderDate,LocalDate dispatchDate,float totalCost,String status) {
        super();
        this.orderId=orderId;
        this.orderDate=orderDate;
        this.dispatchDate=dispatchDate;
        this.totalCost=totalCost;
        this.status=status;
    }

    public int getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }
    public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }
    public LocalDate getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }
    public void setOrderDate(LocalDate orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    public LocalDate getDispatchDate() {
        return dispatchDate;
    }
        public void setDispatchDate(LocalDate dispatchDate) {
            this.dispatchDate = dispatchDate;
        }
        public float getTotalCost() {
            return totalCost;
        }
        public void setTotalCost(float totalCost) {
            this.totalCost = totalCost;
        }
    
        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }
```

```
orderid | dispatchdate | orderdate  | status | totalcost
---------+--------------+------------+--------+-----------
       9 | 2020-01-08   | 2020-01-08 | pass   |         0
       8 | 2018-01-08   | 2018-01-08 | pass   |       100
```

```
 @Override
    public List<Order> showAllOrders(LocalDate date) {

        EntityManagerFactory emf =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPA-PU");
        EntityManager em= emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    
         Query query = em.createQuery("from Order ord where ord.orderdate=:date");

         List<Order> orders= query.getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
        return orders;
    }
```

also tried "from Order where date=:date" and tried after changing orderdate to orderDate as my entity class the property is spelled as orderDate then it gives

> org.hibernate.QueryException:Named parameter not bound : date

I don't know what Iam doing wrong here.

This is the failure trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: orderdate of: com.cg.oam.entities.Order [from com.cg.oam.entities.Order ord where ord.orderdate=:date]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:734)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at com.cg.oam.repository.OrderRepositoryImplementation.showAllOrders(OrderRepositoryImplementation.java:96)
    at com.cg.oam.service.OrderServiceImplementation.showAllOrders(OrderServiceImplementation.java:77)
    at com.cg.oam.test.service.OrderTest.testShowAllOrderByDate(OrderTest.java:90)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: orderdate of: com.cg.oam.entities.Order [from com.cg.oam.entities.Order ord where ord.orderdate=:date]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: orderdate of: com.cg.oam.entities.Order
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2038)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:412)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:695)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:1055)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1308)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4778)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4244)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2166)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:832)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:626)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192)
    ... 77 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message error is telling what's wrong:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException:Named parameter not bound : date
```

The query has a parameter but the value of the parameter is not set.
You need to call `setParameter`:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("from Order ord where ord.orderDate=:date");
query = query.setParameter("date", date);
List<Order> orders= query.getResultList();
```

The other error, as you've already guessed, was a typo. You need to use the attribute name of the entity in JPQL queries, so it's `orderDate` (and not `orderdate`).